# IDE for Android and iOS development, 100% from browser (no need to install Android Studio locally)

Tags: software-development, ide

I'm looking for a development environment to do Android and iOS apps with the following requirements :

- same code for Android and iOS (so I thought about Flutter? but maybe there are other solutions)
- everything is done from the browser: the IDE *is in the browser*, you build from the browser, and finally you download the APK, etc.
- you don't have to download/install Android Studio and other build tools locally

Comment: For much are you willing to pay for such a solution, because you won't get it for free as app building requires a lot of resources. Considering WebUSB there might be a way to realize a web based IDE for Android. But for iOS a lot of tools are required which are only available for MacOS (e.g. app signing). So the only way would be to use a MacOS on server side. Also the required Apple developer account is a problem.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I'm willing to pay for such a solution. It's ok if it's Android-only as a starting point, and if it does not cover the iOS case.